# Getting NAs when parsing dates in readr using col_types

Tags: r, date, parsing

I have a [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aGOZdXhVDuRTilpypIRYD29yJppcU5Sc/view?usp=sharing) dataset and am trying to parse dates by using col_types specification

```
dailyActivityMerged <- read_csv("/cloud/project/Fitabase Data/dailyActivity_merged.csv", 
                            col_types = list(
                              Id = col_double(),
                              ActivityDate = col_date(format = "%m %d %Y"),
                              TotalSteps = col_double(),
                              TotalDistance = col_double(),
                              TrackerDistance = col_double(),
                              LoggedActivitiesDistance = col_double(),
                              VeryActiveDistance = col_double(),
                              ModeratelyActiveDistance = col_double(),
                              LightActiveDistance = col_double(),
                              SedentaryActiveDistance = col_double(),
                              VeryActiveMinutes = col_double(),
                              FairlyActiveMinutes = col_double(),
                              LightlyActiveMinutes = col_double(),
                              SedentaryMinutes = col_double(),
                              Calories = col_double()
                            ))
```

but i am getting an error and all dates are being converted to NA in the ActivityDate column.

Can you tell me why this is happening and how to get the dates in date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the format should be `%m/%d/%Y` instead  and not `%m %d %Y` as per the column format in the data showed in the link

```
library(readr)
dailyActivityMerged <- read_csv("/cloud/project/Fitabase Data/dailyActivity_merged.csv", 
                            col_types = list(
                              Id = col_double(),
                              ActivityDate = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                              TotalSteps = col_double(),
                              TotalDistance = col_double(),
                              TrackerDistance = col_double(),
                              LoggedActivitiesDistance = col_double(),
                              VeryActiveDistance = col_double(),
                              ModeratelyActiveDistance = col_double(),
                              LightActiveDistance = col_double(),
                              SedentaryActiveDistance = col_double(),
                              VeryActiveMinutes = col_double(),
                              FairlyActiveMinutes = col_double(),
                              LightlyActiveMinutes = col_double(),
                              SedentaryMinutes = col_double(),
                              Calories = col_double()
                            ))
```

-check the structure now

```
> str(dailyActivityMerged)
spec_tbl_df [940 × 15] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Id                      : num [1:940] 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 ...
 $ ActivityDate            : Date[1:940], format: "2016-04-12" "2016-04-13" "2016-04-14" "2016-04-15" ...
 $ TotalSteps              : num [1:940] 13162 10735 10460 9762 12669 ...
 $ TotalDistance           : num [1:940] 8.5 6.97 6.74 6.28 8.16 ...
 $ TrackerDistance         : num [1:940] 8.5 6.97 6.74 6.28 8.16 ...
 $ LoggedActivitiesDistance: num [1:940] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ VeryActiveDistance      : num [1:940] 1.88 1.57 2.44 2.14 2.71 ...
 $ ModeratelyActiveDistance: num [1:940] 0.55 0.69 0.4 1.26 0.41 ...
 $ LightActiveDistance     : num [1:940] 6.06 4.71 3.91 2.83 5.04 ...
 $ SedentaryActiveDistance : num [1:940] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ VeryActiveMinutes       : num [1:940] 25 21 30 29 36 38 42 50 28 19 ...
 $ FairlyActiveMinutes     : num [1:940] 13 19 11 34 10 20 16 31 12 8 ...
 $ LightlyActiveMinutes    : num [1:940] 328 217 181 209 221 164 233 264 205 211 ...
 $ SedentaryMinutes        : num [1:940] 728 776 1218 726 773 ...
 $ Calories                : num [1:940] 1985 1797 1776 1745 1863 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   Id = col_double(),
  ..   ActivityDate = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
  ..   TotalSteps = col_double(),
  ..   TotalDistance = col_double(),
  ..   TrackerDistance = col_double(),
  ..   LoggedActivitiesDistance = col_double(),
  ..   VeryActiveDistance = col_double(),
  ..   ModeratelyActiveDistance = col_double(),
  ..   LightActiveDistance = col_double(),
  ..   SedentaryActiveDistance = col_double(),
  ..   VeryActiveMinutes = col_double(),
  ..   FairlyActiveMinutes = col_double(),
  ..   LightlyActiveMinutes = col_double(),
  ..   SedentaryMinutes = col_double(),
  ..   Calories = col_double()
  .. )
```